# TCL script search string from file1 & file 2 and replace it in file1

Tags: python, shell, awk, tcl

I have 2 files. I want to find specific content from file 2 and replace the complete instance string in the file 1 where that content matches.

Partial Content of file 1:

```
// ALL xyz   vev1      Par/abc/a_xyz123_place_INT
// ALL ieug  vev2      Par/abc/b_pqr987_place_INT
```

Partial Content of file 2:

```
// Vev Inst: 'Par/pgh/fgf/a_xyz123_inst'
// Vev Inst: 'Par/pgh/sgg/gdgg/b_pqr987_inst'
```

--

Here, script should start search for the content between last "/" and "_place_INT" from file 1. For ex:
Searched content from file 1 will be :

```
a_xyz123 
b_pqr987
```

Now script should look for this search contents in file 2 search entire string and replace this searched content in file 1:
For ex: script will search "a_xyz123" in file 2 so it will get this string 'Par/pgh/fgf/**a_xyz123**_inst'.
Now script should replace this in file1.

Expected output file1:

```
// ALL xyz   vev1    'Par/pgh/fgf/a_xyz123_inst'
// ALL ieug  vev2    'Par/pgh/sgg/gdgg/b_pqr987_inst'
```

Here you can see Par/abc/a_xyz123_place_INT is replaced with 'Par/pgh/fgf/a_xyz123_inst' as both of these has a_xyz123.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried in awk but didnt work and new to TCL so needed help:
awk -F "[ =:,]" '
  FNR==NR { a[$4]=$0; next } 
  $2 in a { 
    split(a[$4],b); 
    for (i=3;i<=NF-1;i+=2) 
      for (j=2;j<=length(b)-1;j+=2) 
        if ($(i+1) == b[j]) 
           line = (line ? line "," : "") $i ":" b[j+1];
    print $1 "=" line; line = "" 
  }' file1 file2

Comment: Add this in your post.

Comment: @programmer34043059 : Did you try the [regexp](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm) command in Tcl? Also, if you don't know Tcl, why are you writing this in Tcl? And why is this question tagged as _python_?

Comment: `I tried in awk but didn't work` - "didn't work" is the worst possible problem description. Post what you tried in your question and tell us in what way it "didn't work" (wrong output, no output, syntax error, core dump, something else?) if you'd like help. And be clear if you're looking for a solution using any one particular tool or not - you put TCL in your subject line so is that the only tool you want to use? If so get rid of all the other tags, if not then remove that from the subject.

Answer (score 1):

tcl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc main {file1 file2} {
    set f2 [open $file2 r]
    set f2contents [read $f2]
    close $f2

    set f1 [open $file1 r]
    while {[gets $f1 line] > 0} {
        if {[regexp {([^/]+)_place_INT$} $line _ pat]} {
            set re [string cat {'[\w/]+} $pat {\w+'}]
            if {[regexp $re $f2contents replacement]} {
                regsub {[\w/]+$} $line $replacement line
            }
        }
        puts $line
    }
    close $f1
}

main {*}$argv
```

Example:

```
$ tclsh demo.tcl file1.txt file2.txt
// ALL xyz   vev1      'Par/pgh/fgf/a_xyz123_inst'
// ALL ieug  vev2      'Par/pgh/sgg/gdgg/b_pqr987_inst'
```

Comment: how to store this in new file?

Comment: I tried executing this script but getting below error:
Seems like "cat" is not working            
`unknown or ambiguous subcommand "cat": must be bytelength, compare, equal, first, index, is, last, length, map, match, range, repeat, replace, reverse, tolower, totitle, toupper, trim, trimleft, trimright, wordend, or wordstart
    while executing
"string cat {'[\w/]+} $pat {\w+'}"
    (procedure "main" line 9)
    invoked from within
"main {*}$argv"
    (file "tcl_script.tcl" line 21)`

Comment: @programmer34043059 Shell redirection is the easy way. And you must be using a really outdated version of tcl if it doesn't have `string cat`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while read line; 
do 
search_str=$(echo ${line}| sed 's#.*\/##g;s#_place_INT##');
replace_str=$(grep -o "'.*${search_str}.*'" file2.txt);
if test -z "$replace_str" 
then 
    echo ${line} >> file1.txt.tmp; 
else 
    echo ${line} | awk -v str="${replace_str}" '{$NF=str; print }' >> file1.txt.tmp; 
fi
done < file1.txt
mv file1.txt.tmp  file1.txt
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thank you @Ed   I try to write code in `awk` but choose easier path. Will update my answer in `awk` tommorow

Comment: You're welcome. The problem with the "easier" path is that, in addition to being extremely slow to run, it contains several insidious bugs that'll come back to bite you later given various input values, contents of directory you run the script from, environment settings, etc. To write it robustly would be far less easy than writing an awk script and then you'd still have speed of execution and portability issues.